# Org Mode Agenda: Trees whose sub-trees don't contain a specific tag

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I want to make an `org-agenda-custom-command` that searches for all top-level trees that don't have a sub-tree with a `"NEXT"` tag. I'm trying to set up a search that I can do at the beginning of the week to make sure that all projects have their next step defined.

I looked into [Special Agenda Views](https://orgmode.org/manual/Special-agenda-views.html) which seems close to what I need, but I couldn't figure out a way to use it to search an entry's sub-tree to determine if an entry should be skipped or not.

Any pointers or suggestions that could get me closer to a solution?

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the special [stuck projects](https://orgmode.org/manual/Stuck-projects.html) agenda view for this (by default `C-c a #`).  It's controlled by a special variable `org-stuck-projects`. According to the manual:

> How to identify stuck projects.
>   This is a list of four items:
>
> 1. A tags/todo/property matcher string that is used to identify a project.
>      See the manual for a description of tag and property searches.
>      The entire tree below a headline matched by this is considered one project.
> 2. A list of TODO keywords identifying non-stuck projects.
>      If the project subtree contains any headline with one of these todo
>      keywords, the project is considered to be not stuck.  If you specify
>      "*" as a keyword, any TODO keyword will mark the project unstuck.
> 3. A list of tags identifying non-stuck projects.
>      If the project subtree contains any headline with one of these tags,
>      the project is considered to be not stuck.  If you specify "*" as
>      a tag, any tag will mark the project unstuck.  Note that this is about
>      the explicit presence of a tag somewhere in the subtree, inherited
>      tags do not count here.  If inherited tags make a project not stuck,
>      use "-TAG" in the tags part of the matcher under (1.) above.
> 4. An arbitrary regular expression matching non-stuck projects.

For 1. we can use `LEVEL=1` to match a top level headline.  For 2. any child marked `NEXT` makes the project not stuck.  3. and 4 we don't need so we'll leave them `nil`.  Thus `(setq org-stuck-projects '("LEVEL=1" ("NEXT") nil nil))` will make the stuck project view show all top level headlines that do not have a child marked "NEXT".